# bat file for running MATLAB code from Notepad++

Tags: matlab, batch-file, cmd, notepad++

I want to write a `.bat` file which, when I push the run button on Notepad++, 
runs my matlab code through the command line

I wrote a simple batch file for running specific code (test.m)

How can I pass other file addresses through Notepad++'s run button to my batch file?

I would also appreciate other solutions.

My code:

```
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "; run('D:\test.m');"
```

Comment: In a batch file you can reference parameters like the file name of file opened in Notepad++ with `%1`, `%2`, ... Run in a command prompt window `call /?` and read the output help for details. So replace `D:\test.m` by `%~1` and find out in documentation of Notepad++ how to run a tool like your batch file with name of active file with full path.

Answer (score 0):

This one I wouldn't use a CMD command, but rather a batch file that runs certain parts of your program. If I understand you correctly, then you want to run the MATLAB program when you click on the icon, as well as notepad++. What I would do is the following.

Right Click on the program, select properties, then change the target line to

```
"[Notepad++ Target Path Here]", "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "; run('D:\test.m');"
```

This should run both programs

Hope this helps!